# Append and replace using awk/sed

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, informatica

I have this file:

```
2016,05,P,0002    ,CJGLOPSD8                                                    
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,051000100,GBP,   ,       -2705248.00                           
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,059999998,GBP,   ,       -3479679.38                           
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061505141,GBP,   ,             -0.40                           
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061505142,GBP,   ,        6207621.00                           
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061505405,GBP,   ,             -0.16                           
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061552000,GBP,   ,             -0.24                           
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061559010,GBP,   ,             -0.44                           
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,062108021,GBP,   ,             -0.34                           
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,063502007,GBP,   ,             -0.28
```

I want to programmatically (in unix, or informatica if possible) grab the first two fields in the top row, concatenate them, append them to the end of each line and remove that first row.

Like so:

```
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,051000100,GBP,,-2705248.00,201605                          
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,059999998,GBP,,-3479679.38,201605                           
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061505141,GBP,,-0.40,201605                           
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061505142,GBP,,6207621.00,201605                           
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061505405,GBP,,-0.16,201605                           
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061552000,GBP,,-0.24,201605                          
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061559010,GBP,,-0.44,201605                         
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,062108021,GBP,,-0.34,201605                        
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,063502007,GBP,,-0.28,201605
```

This is my current attempt:

```
awk -vvar1=`cat OF\ OPSDOWN8.CSV | head -1 | cut -d',' -f1` -vvar2=`cat OF\ OPSDOWN8.CSV | head -1 | cut -d',' -f2` 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {print $0, var 1var2}' OF\ OPSDOWN8.CSV> OF_OPSDOWN8.csv
```

Any pointers? I've tried looking around the forum but can only find answers to part of my question.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{val=$1$2;next} {gsub(/ */,"");print $0,val}' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` - This block will set FS (Field Separator) and OFS (Output Field Separator) as `,`.
- `NR==1` - Working with line number 1. Here, `$1` and `$2` denotes field number.
- `print $0,val` - Printing `$0` (whole line) and stored value from `val`.

Comment: No need to put the blank char inside a bracket expression, it's not a metacharacter.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following `awk` command:

```
awk 'NR==1{d=$1$2;next}{$(NF+1)=d;gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"")}1' FS=, OFS=, file
```

Explanation:

- `NR==1{d=$1$2;next}` applies on line 1 and set's a variable `d(ate)` to the value of the first and the second field. The variable is being used when processing the remaining lines. `next` tells `awk` to go ahead with the next line right away without processing further instructions on this line.
- `{$(NF+1)=d;gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"")}1` appends a new field to the line (`NF` is the number of fields, assigning `d` to `$(NF+1)` effectively adds a field. `gsub()` is used to removing spaces. `1` at the end always evaluates to true and makes awk print the modified line.
- `FS=,` is a command line argument. It set's the input field delimiter to `,`.
- `OFS=,` is a command line argument. It set's the output field delimiter to `,`.

Output:

```
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,051000100,GBP,,-2705248.00,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,059999998,GBP,,-3479679.38,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061505141,GBP,,-0.40,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061505142,GBP,,6207621.00,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061505405,GBP,,-0.16,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061552000,GBP,,-0.24,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061559010,GBP,,-0.44,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,062108021,GBP,,-0.34,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,063502007,GBP,,-0.28,201605
```

Comment: When 2 variables must have the same value it's best to set them together to that value rather than separately at opposite ends of a program: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}...`.

Comment: While I would generally agree, I prefer to save the `BEGIN` block in this case / such cases.

Comment: Why's that? Assuming you have your reasons, consider at least putting them side by side before they are used `awk -F, -v OFS=, ...`. rather than at opposite ends of the script. Setting variables in the file list at the end is counter-intuitive and makes it harder to write scripts that need to parse file names (e.g. and is only useful when you need to avoid interpretation of backslashes and/or need to change values of a variable between files (e.g. `awk '...' FS=, file1 FS=; file2`.

Comment: Getting a compile error? Saying syntax / illegal statement.

Comment: @EdMorton Definitely I see your point. But imo for a command line one liner sometimes other rules are more important. For example keeping the 80 chars limit, even if used in a conditional or inside an already indented block - if applicable(!). I don't say this reason has the highest priority over other aspects but I really don't like to use the `BEGIN` block for things which can be done using arguments. In this case it makes the difference between 76 and 82 chars.

Comment: @Elrodge No, it is not saying that. Can you be please send the complete error message?

Comment: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @Elrodge you are using old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris). If you're on Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk or, much better, get/use GNU awk.

Comment: @EdMorton you genius! Using usr/xpg4/bin/awk worked like a charm. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

With sed :

```
sed '1{s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),.*/\1\2/;h;d};/.*/G;s/\n/,/;s/ //g' file
```

in ERE mode :

```
sed -r '1{s/([^,]*),([^,]*),.*/\1\2/;h;d};/.*/G;s/\n/,/;s/ //g' file
```

Output :

```
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,051000100,GBP,,-2705248.00,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,059999998,GBP,,-3479679.38,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061505141,GBP,,-0.40,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061505142,GBP,,6207621.00,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061505405,GBP,,-0.16,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061552000,GBP,,-0.24,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,061559010,GBP,,-0.44,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,062108021,GBP,,-0.34,201605
00,BBF,BBDFTP999,063502007,GBP,,-0.28,201605
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1s/,//;1s/,.*//;1h;1d;s/ //g;G;s/\n/,/' file
```

For the first line only: remove the first comma, remove from the next comma to the end of the line, store the amended line in the hold space (HS) and then delete the current line (the `d` abruptly ends processing). For subsequent lines: remove all spaces, append the HS and replace the newline (from the `G` command) with a comma.

Or if you prefer:

```
sed '1{s/,//;s/,.*//;h;d};s/ //g;G;s/\n/,/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Informatica for this, use two Source Qualifiers. Read the file twice - just one line in one SQ (filter out the rest) and in the second SQ read the whole file except the first line (skip header). Join the two on dummy port and you're done.